# Почему выдает ошибку PermissionError?

Tags: python, файловая-система, ос

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(current_start_path + r'\update'):  # Список всех файлов и папок в директории
    for file in files:
        if file == 'test.txt':
            os.replace(f'{current_start_path}/update\{file}', current_start_path)
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Danila/PycharmProjects/sendDZ/main.py", line 122, in <module>
    os.replace(f'{current_start_path}/update\{file}'.replace('\\', '/'), current_start_path.replace('\\', '/'))
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Отказано в доступе: 'C:/Users/Danila/PycharmProjects/sendDZ/update/test.txt' -> 'C:/Users/Danila/PycharmProjects/sendDZ'
```

Comment: Кажется вы пытаетесь записать файл в директорию. `os.replace(f'{current_start_path}/update\{file}', current_start_path+ new_file_name)` поидее должно работать.

Comment: @Kers, действительно сработало. Хотя не понятно почему.  В другом коде без этого исправления всё работает, а здесь  нет. в любом случаи спасибо!

Comment: Сработало потому что в данном случае вы копируете файл в файл, а изначально было что файл должен стать папкой. На что и ругалась система запрещая доступ.